# ¿Como puedo subir archivos en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Me gustaría saber como generar un formulario en Rails para que pueda subir archivos sin problemas, he leído varios tutoriales, pero aun me anda costando un poco el lograr hacerlo.

Controlador:

```
class ContratosController < ApplicationController
  DOCUMENTO_TOKEN = "public/uploads/documentotoken"

  def index
    @tituloindex = "Emitir Asset";
    @tituloinfo = "Info de Contrato";
    @coins = params[:coins];

    if request.post?
      documento = params[:documento];

      #Nombre Original del Documento
      nombre = documento.original_filename;

      #Directorio donde se va a guardar
      directorio = DOCUMENTO_TOKEN;

      #Extension del archivo
      extension = nombre.slice(nombre.rindex("."), nombre.length).downcase;

      if extension == ".pdf" or extension == ".jpg"
        #ruta del archivo
        path = File.join(directorio, nombre);
      else
        @formato_erroneo = true;
      end
    end
  end

  def info
  end
end
```

Vista:

```
<h1><%= @tituloindex; %></h1>
<table width="600px">
<%= form_tag({:controller => "contratos", :action => "index"}, :method => "post", :multipart => true) do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag "coins", "Initial Coins" %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag "coins", "", :size => 20, :maxlenght => 5, :placeholder => "coins", :required => "required" %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag "decimals", "decimals" %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag "decimals", "", :size => 20, :maxlenght => 5, :placeholder => "decimals", :required => "required" %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag "tokenname", "Token Name" %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag "tokenname", "", :size => 20, :maxlenght => 5, :placeholder => "Token Name", :required => "required" %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag "tokenpreffix", "Token Preffix" %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag "tokenpreffix", "", :size => 20, :maxlenght => 5, :placeholder => "Token Preffix", :required => "required" %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag "selecttoken", "Select Token" %></td>
    <td><%= select_tag "selecttoken",
                       "<option>crowdsale</option>
                        <option>ShareHolder Company</option>
                        <option>Simple Token</option>
                        <option>Pannic</option>
                        <option>comoditie</option>".html_safe %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%=label_tag "documento","Documento de Identidad (Solo *.pdf o *.jpg)"%></td>
    <td><%= file_field_tag "documento", :required => "required" %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Enviar" %>
<% end %>

<div id="resultados" >
  <% if @coins %>
    <%= "Se han enviado #{@coins} Lescovex ha su cuenta" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= "verifique bien los datos" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora? Lo más sencillo sería utilizar alguna gema; te recomiendo evaluar _[CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)_ y _[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)_.

Comment: no he usado alguna gema, solo asi codigo directo, ya resubi el codigo para que vean como voy

Comment: ¿Te genera algún error al enviar la forma? En caso que así sea, ¿podrías mostrarlo también?

Comment: NameError (undefined local variable or method `archivo' for #<ContratosController:0x005612f0fc6a08>):

Comment: ¿Te da alguna línea? ¿Podrías agregar el error completo en tu pregunta?

Comment: ya resolvi mi problema, mi archivo nunca recibio las correciones en servidor (no se porque) pero ya envia mis archivos sin problemas

Comment: @ShadowMyst si encontraste una solución, podrías ponerla como respuesta, así si alguien mas tiene tu mismo problema podrá saber que hacer